# Never ending VBA, neither getting the result. Please tell me the error in this code

Tags: vba, excel

```
Option Explicit

Sub dowhileloop()

Dim x As Long
Dim sumx As Long
Sheets("test data").Select
x = 2
Do While Cells(x, 2) <> " "
DoEvents
sumx = Cells(x, 5).Value
If Cells(x, 2) = Cells(x + 1, 2) And Cells(x, 4) = Cells(x + 1, 4) Then
sumx = sumx + Cells(x + 1, 5).Value
Range("F2:G100").Select
Else
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Never ending VBA, neither getting the result. Please tell me the error in this code.

Comment: Aside from not changing `x`, what is the purpose of your loop? Why select some cells?

Comment: eg. x=2,

If value in cell B2=B3 and D2=D3, then I want the output as E2+E3, and the value will get stored in another cell eg F2

then, if B3=B4 and D3=D4, then output is E3+E4

I will remove the select statment

Comment: But there is no output anywhere. You do not place `sumx` in a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not incrementing `x` - so it never changes.

Comment: I changed it, added (x = x + 1) before (Else)

however it is still not giving any output and it still a never ending code

Comment: Did you see @Matt's comment about changing the `Do While Cells(x, 2) <> "[SPACE]"` to `Do While Cells(x, 2) <> ""` ? That said, @Ralph appears to have rewritten the whole thing for you which I'm sure will work :)

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you are looking for something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub dowhileloop()

Dim x As Long
Dim sumX As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test data")

For x = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    sumX = ws.Cells(x, 5).Value2
    If ws.Cells(x, 2) = ws.Cells(x + 1, 2) And ws.Cells(x, 4) = ws.Cells(x + 1, 4) Then
        sumX = sumX + ws.Cells(x + 1, 5).Value
    Else
        ' ...do something else?
    End If
Next x

ws.Activate
ws.Range("F2:G100").Select

End Sub
```

Changes:

1. There is no need to `select` anything just to manipulate the data on that sheet. It is especially not necessary to `select` something multiple times in a `Loop`. But if you want to make sure that a certain range is selected at the end of your program then you might as well put it to the end of your code.
2. I changed the `Do while ... Loop` for a `For ... Next` loop. This loop is definite while the `Do while ... Loop` has a tendency to get infinite if you are not careful. Hence, I always try to avoid them.
3. The code is now more explicit and fully qualified using `Set ws = ...` in the beginning and then using `ws.` in all the `Cells` and `Range` refernces afterwards.
4. The line `DoEvents` does not strike me as being necessary in this context. Hence, I removed it.

The rest is pretty much the same. Still, if you have questions then don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I tried the code, however did not get any output(it didn't give any compilation error though)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I tried the code, however, did not get any output(it didn't give any compilation error though)


Option Explicit



Sub dowhileloop()

Dim x As Long
Dim sumX As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim n As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test data")

For x = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    sumX = ws.Cells(x, 5).Value2
    If ws.Cells(x, 2) = ws.Cells(x + n, 2) And ws.Cells(x, 4) = ws.Cells(x + n, 4) Then
        sumX = sumX + ws.Cells(x + n, 5).Value
    Else
        n = n + 1
        
    End If
Next x

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

a) Space you need to remove in  - `Do While Cells(x, 2) <> ""`

B) increment `x = x + 1`